# Can anyone tell me the problem[s] in this bubble sort?

Tags: c, sorting, bubble-sort

I have looked at several examples of this bubble sort but can't seem to find out what's wrong in mine,
I'm weak with loops and such.
I have to explain this to my class tomorrow so it'd be great if someone could help, **thanks**.

```
int main(){

int i,n,j,temp;
int a[] = {5,4,3,2,1};
n    = 5;

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j = 0;j<n-i-1;j++){
        if(a[j]>a[j+1]){            
            temp = a[j];                
            a[j] = a[j+1];
            a[j+1] = temp;
        }
    }
    printf("%d",a[i]);
}}
```

Comment: What goes wrong? What if you print out when each change occurs?

Comment: Your `printf` is in the wrong place! Wait until the sort is complete, then have a separate loop printing out the values - you'll be amazed at the results!

Comment: At least put the printf() in a separate loop. And add a '\n'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is not in your bubble sort.you have miss placed `printf` remove it and add a loop like this after sorting loops:

```
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track the sorting process using a call of `printf` then you need correctly to specify the index of the element that is taking its final positions.

Change the call of printf

```
printf("%d",a[i]);
             ^^^
```

to the following

```
printf("%d ",a[j]);
             ^^^
```

In this case you will get the output

```
5 4 3 2 1
```

That is at first the most big element takes its final position. Then the second biggest element among remaining elements takes its final position and so on.

Pay attention to that you should declare variables in the minimal scope where they are used. And instead of magic numbers like 5 use named constants.

You can also add to the program an output of the result array.

Here is your updated program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int a[] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        size_t j = 0;
        for ( ; j < N - i - 1; j++ )
        {
            if ( a[j+1] < a[j] )
            {            
                int temp = a[j];                
                a[j] = a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
        printf( "%d ", a[j] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Its output is

```
5 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 5
```